# I need a conversion of string to decimal using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

Json:
{
"Amt":"99.00"
}

Need output like

{
"Amt":99.00
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$number function](https://docs.jsonata.org/numeric-functions#number), see it live on the playground: https://stedi.link/ZYFdShe

```
{
  "Amt": $number(Amt)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but I need 00 also after decimal point pls help me to resolve

Comment: It's not possible in Javascript, try putting `{ "Amt": 99.00 }` in a nodejs or browser console and see what you get.